# Google appengine shows zero instance hour usage, even though two instances are up

Tags: google-app-engine

I recently deployed a `Node.js` app in google appengine.

When I go to appengine dashboard and check resource usage, no frontend instance hour usae is shown.

[image]

But, in `Instances` tab, it shows that two instances are up.

[image]

Since the instances are up, and I have made several http requests to the application, I didn't expect to see zero instance hour usage. Also, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16782270/1015678) answer, 15 instance minutes charged for every instance spin up.

So what could be the reason for showing zero instance hour usage in my app?

(I checked the usage several times within last 24 hours, so this cannot be due to the update delay in dashboard)